# How can I convert boost::gregorian::greg_year to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, boost, concatenation

I am splitting a file that contains 40 years worth of data into individual years.  So I want to do something like this:

```
// get line, convert substring of that line to boost::gregorian::date, and then
// get the year from it.  after doing all that,

std::string path = "data_";
path += year // where year is of type boost::gregorian::greg_year
path += ".csv";
```

When the next line comes from "next year", create a new path.  Thus at the end I should have the following files:

```
data_1979.csv
data_1980.csv
data_1981.csv
```

etc.  But how can I concatenate a boost::gregorian::greg_year with a string?

Answer (score 1):

`greg_year`'s `operator()` returns the value as `unsigned short`. You can transform this into a `std::string` using `std::to_string()`.

Comment: is it operator() ? I think it's operator unsigned short